# Сделать так чтоб скрипты добавлялись в базовом классе

Tags: php, kohana, framework

Вопрос:
У меня есть базовый класс «*class Controller_BaseC extends Controller_Template*», у которого есть свое view «'*baseV*'»
и класс «*class Controller_IndexC extends Controller_BaseC*» **без** view.
В классе «IndexC», я определил скрипты «$this->template->scripts = array('media/Js/loadscript.js');»
Но в базовом, я тоже определил «$this->template->scripts = array('media/Js/statr.js');»

Как мне написать, чтоб скрипты «IndexC» не затирали скрипты «BaseC», а добавлялись к ним?

Comment: `$a = array(); $a[] = 'script.1.js'; $a[] = 'script.2.js';`

Comment: извиняюсь, не уловил вашей мысли, в двух классах я заполняю массивы, теперь мне надо их объединить в выдать в view, т.е. " $this->template->scripts ="

Comment: Даполнил ответ, до правильного.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы в ПХП добавить значение в массив нужно использовать следующий синтакс:

```
<?php
    $a = [];
    $a[] = 'a';
    $a[] = 'b';
    // $a = array ('a', 'b')
```

Если же вопрос  как в наследуемом классе подобрать значения из отцовского то:

```
<?php

    class A {
        public function getTemplates() {
            return $this->_templates;
        }

        public function initTemplates() {
            $this->_initTemplates();
        }

        protected $_templates = ['1', '2', '3'];
    }

    class B extends A {
        protected function _initTemplates() {
            $this->_templates = array_merge(
                $this->_templates,
                $this->_getClassTemplates()
            );
        }

        protected function _getClassTemplates() {
            return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        }
    }

    class C extends B {
        protected function _getClassTemplates() {
            return array_merge(
                parent::_getClassTemplates(),
                ['d', 'e', 'f']
            );
        }
    }

    $a = new C();
    $a->initTemplates();
    var_dump($a->getTemplates()); die();
```

Не красиво,  массивно но работать будет.

P.S.:
Мне кажеться что вы сделали архетиктурную ошибку.
Не зная кода трудно сказать где.

Comment: Вы не ошиблись в первом комментарии. В обоих контроллерах, нужно подключать скрипты таким образом: "**$this->template->scripts = array();
        $this->template->scripts[] = 'media/Js/watch.js'; ....
        $this->template->scripts[] = 'media/Js/analytics.js';**" ну и т.д. и все объединится